# creating a dataframe with multiple conditions and then performing grouby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, pandas-groupby

```
Country     Access_fy   Access_month    Order__month Customer_ID    Order__fy    resubs   terminated
     AU           FY12         Jul-2012      Jul-2012        321021      FY12          1      1
     AU           FY12         Jul-2012      Jul-2012        154905      FY12          0      1
     AU           FY12         Jul-2012      Jul-2012        154905      FY12          0      1
     AU           FY12         Jul-2012      Jul-2012        727796      FY12          1      1
     AU           FY12         Jul-2012      Jul-2012        321021      FY12          1      1
     PH           FY22         Nov-2021      Nov-2021        2381271     FY22          0      1
     AU           FY22         Nov-2021      Sep-2021        4151218     FY22          0      1
```

Given the above dataframe, is there any other elegant way to groupby with a condition? I want to calculate the number of churned customers and resubscribed customer within the same FY year along with month of their churned and resubscribed month. So Access_month is the churned month and Order_month is the resubscribed_month in the given dataframe.
I did try with the following code but not able to achieve the correct output:

```
churned=[]


df = final_df.filter(['Country_Code','Access_To_fy','Access_To_month','Order_Date_month','Customer_ID','Order_Date_fy']) df = df.query('Access_To_fy == Order_Date_fy') 
x = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Country_Code','Access_To_fy','Access_To_month','Order_Date_month'])['Customer_ID'].count().reset_index()) 
churned.append(x)
churned = (pd.concat(churned,ignore_index = False).reset_index(drop=True))
```

The output if above is:

```
Country_Code Access_To_fy Access_To_month Order_Date_month  Customer_ID
           AU         FY12        Apr-2012         Apr-2012            1
           AU         FY12        Jul-2012         Apr-2012            1
           AU         FY12        Jul-2012         Jul-2012            5
```

similarly for resubscriber. I have used

```
resubs=[]
df2 = final_df.filter(['Country_Code','Access_To_fy','Access_To_month','Order_Date_month','Customer_ID','Order_Date_fy','resubs_flag'])
df2 = df2.query('Access_To_fy == Order_Date_fy and resubs_flag ==1')
y = pd.DataFrame(df2.groupby(['Country_Code','Access_To_fy','Order_Date_month'])['Customer_ID'].count()).reset_index()
resubs.append(y)
resubs = (pd.concat(resubs,ignore_index = False).reset_index(drop=True))
```

the output of above code is:

```
Country_Code    Access_To_fy    Order_Date_month    Access_To_month Customer_ID
  AU               FY12              Jul-2012          Jul-2012         3
  AU               FY14              Jun-2014          Jan-2014         1
  AU               FY15              Apr-2015          Apr-2015         22
  AU               FY15              Apr-2015          Feb-2015         3
  AU               FY15              Apr-2015          Jan-2015         1
```

Please help

Comment: so two separate dataframes?

Comment: No. A single dataframe. The output should be, for a year in a given month  the number of churned subscriber who resubscribed in the consecutive month for the same year. for example if a subscriber is churned in 2012 in a month May-2012 then he resubscribed in other month of 2012 say, july 2012